# Angular 5 - How to generate definition files

Tags: angular, angular5, npm-link

I have been trying several ways but I am not able to understand how to generate definition files for my project. I have two angular-cli generated applications A and B, I want A to consume B as a package (with npm link). As far as I understand I need to create an index.ts file in project B with all the modules I want to export and run 'ng build' command. I have seen that only creates the bundles but not the definition files, how can I generate definition files? Is this the correct approach?.

I have tried some other options like 'rollup' and 'ngmakelib' but it seems to be pretty hard to do that simple task. Do we have an easy way to generate Angular 5 projects as libraries and consume that libraries from another projects?

Comment: Why couldn't you use ngmakelib? It should be as easy as: `ngmakelib src/app/mymodule/mymodule.module.ts mymodule-library` and then you should be able to use npm install on the resulting tar.gz file.

Comment: @PeterSalomonsen that's not useful since I need to install the tar.gz file, I wanted to use "npm link" so if the library change all the components will pick the latest changes when using "npm install"

Comment: OK so if the output is a folder rather than a tar.gz it would work?

Comment: I can't remember why I declined to use ngmakelib, I guess it is because it does not use rollup, that's why I finally use ngpackgr

Comment: It does use rollup. No stress though. Just curious why it didn't work.

Comment: @AlejandroMorán ng-packagr doesn't work...

Comment: @smaudet It is, it has also been included in Angular 6 to create library projects with angular-cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a high level, here are the steps you would need to do to create a reusable Angular module (all done without webpack):

1. Create a `public_api.ts` file within your `src` folder. This should contain all your exported symbols, so that users of your library can do: `import { symbol } from 'your-library'`
2. Copy your `src` folder to a `build/dist` folder making sure to inline your templates. I use `gulp` and `gulp-inline-ng2-template` for this.

**gulpfile.js**

```
    const gulp = require('gulp');
    const replace = require('gulp-replace');
    const inlineNg2Template = require('gulp-inline-ng2-template');
    const del = require('del');

    gulp.task('clean', function () {
        return del([
           "dist/**"
        ], { force: true });
    });


    gulp.task('copy-public-api', ['clean'], function () {
        return gulp.src([
            '../src/public_api.ts'
        ])
        .pipe(replace('./app', './src'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))

    });
    gulp.task('copy-src', ['copy-public-api'], function () {
        return gulp.src([
           '../src/app/**/*.ts',
           '!../src/app/**/*.spec.ts'
        ])
        .pipe(inlineNg2Template({ base: '../src', useRelativePaths: true }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/src'))
    });
```

**public_api.ts**

```
    export * from './app/app.module';
    // ... other exports ...
```

3. Create a tsconfig file for `ngc`.  You'll be using `ngc` to generate the necessary metadata files. Here are the settings that I use. The file is placed in a "build" folder (notice the relative paths for `typeRoots` and `paths`).

**build/tsconfig.json**

```
    {
        "compilerOptions": {
            "baseUrl": ".",
            "rootDir": ".",
            "outDir": "",
            "paths": {
                "*": [
                    "../node_modules/*"
                ]
            },             
            "declaration": true,
            "stripInternal": true,
            "noImplicitAny": true,
            "strictNullChecks": true,
            "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
            "moduleResolution": "node",
            "module": "es2015",
            "target": "es5",
            "lib": [
                "es2015",
                "dom"
            ],
            "skipLibCheck": true,
            "typeRoots": [     
                "../node_modules/@types/"  
            ], 
            "experimentalDecorators": true,
            "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "inlineSources": true
        },
        "files": [
            "dist/public_api.ts"
        ],
        "angularCompilerOptions": {
            "annotateForClosureCompiler": true,
            "strictMetadataEmit": false,
            "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
            "flatModuleOutFile": "index.js",
            "flatModuleId": "ng-module-template"
        }    

    }
```

The `angularCompilerOptions` ensure that one metadata file is created (index.js).

4. Use `ngc` to compile the module from the build folder. Make sure to install `@angular/compiler` and `@angular/compiler-cli`:

   ```
   ../node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig.json
   ```
5. Deploy only the files that are needed.  I deploy from `build\dist` to `dist`:

   ```
   gulp.task('build', [], function (done) {
       gulp.src([
           'dist/index.js',
           'dist/public_api.js',
           'dist/index.metadata.json',
           'dist/**/*.d.ts',
           '!../src/app/**/*.spec.ts'
       ], { base: 'dist' })
           .pipe(gulp.dest('../dist'))
           .on('end', function () {
               del('dist/**', { force: true }).then(function () {
                   done();
               });
           });
   });
   ```
6. Make sure you modify your package.json to point to index.js:

   ```
   {
     "name": "ng-module-template",
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "description": "",
     "main": "dist/index.js",
     "typings": "dist/index.d.ts",
   }
   ```

### Optional: Creating Bundles

Here is a gulp build target for compiling and creating bundles using rollup with treeshaking:

```
gulp.task('compile', ['copy-src'], function (done) {
    gulp.src('tsconfig.json')
        .pipe(shell(['"../node_modules/.bin/ngc" -p <%= file.path %>']))
        .on('end', function () {
            del('node_modules/**', { force: true }).then(function () {
                done();
            });
        });
});

gulp.task('bundle', ['compile'], function (done) {
    var external = [
        '@angular/core',
        '@angular/common',
        '@angular/compiler',
        '@angular/core',
        '@angular/http',
        '@angular/platform-browser',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
        '@angular/router',
        '@angular/router-deprecated'
    ];

    var globals = {
        '@angular/core': 'vendor._angular_core',
        '@angular/http': 'vendor._angular_http',
        '@angular/platform-browser': 'vendor._angular_platformBrowser',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'vendor._angular_platformBrowserDynamic',
        '@angular/router-deprecated': 'vendor._angular_routerDeprecated'
    };

    rollup.rollup({
        input: 'dist/index.js',
        onwarn: function (warning) {
            if (warning.message.indexOf("treating it as an external dependency") > -1)
                return;


            console.warn(warning.message);
        }

    }).then(function (bundle) {
        var umd = bundle.write({
            file: `dist/bundles/${pkg.name}.umd.js`,
            format: 'umd',
            exports: 'named',
            name: pkg.name,
            sourcemap: true,
            external: external,
            globals: globals
        });
        var cjs = bundle.write({
            file: `dist/bundles/${pkg.name}.cjs.js`,
            format: 'cjs',
            exports: 'named',
            name: pkg.name,
            sourcemap: true,
            external: external,
            globals: globals
        });
        var amd = bundle.write({
            file: `dist/bundles/${pkg.name}.amd.js`,
            format: 'amd',
            exports: 'named',
            name: pkg.name,
            sourcemap: true,
            external: external,
            globals: globals
        });

        var es = bundle.write({
            file: `dist/index.es5.js`,
            format: 'es',
            exports: 'named',
            name: pkg.name,
            sourcemap: true,
            external: external,
            globals: globals

        });

        return Promise.all([umd, cjs, amd, es]).then(function () {
            done();
        });

    });
});
```

### Source Code Demo

*Pre-requisites*

> Angular5+ 
>   Git (installed locally if you are publishing to a local folder)

https://github.com/angular-patterns/ng-module-template

## Build Targets

**npm run dev**

For development

**npm run build**

For production app build (outputs to dist folder)

**npm run build-module**

For a module build (outputs to dist folder)

**npm run publish**

For publishing to `c:\packages` using git. Alternatively, run `npm publish` to publish to `npm`.

**npm run name-module -- --(module-name)**

For naming the module. This modifies the source.

## Installing from c:\packages

```
npm install c:\packages\<module-name>
```

Comment: Thanks for such a good answer! I will try it as soon as possible but I think I need to adapt it to webpack, I'm trying to do this with an angular-cli generated project and it is getting so hard.

Comment: That generator in the link 'ng-module-template' seems to be not working, it shows me the following error 'Unexpected value 'TestComponent' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a NgModule annotation.'

Comment: There is no TestComponent in the source. Are you sure you cloned the repo?

Comment: I've created my own component, what version of angular cli are you using?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way of creating reusable modules using angular cli

Comment: I've accepted your answers since it is a really good guide of how to achieve that goal, I did it in a different way, now I am using 'ng-packagr' tool to generate my libraries, thanks for your help.

Comment: Once you add your TestComponent, you can run the target `npm run name-module -- --MyModule` where `MyModule` is the name of your module.   Then run `npm publish` to publish to NPM. Once published to NPM, run `npm install MyModule --save` on a brand new project.  Import the module as you normally would, then use the TestComponent directive.

Comment: Yes, that's the tricky part, I wanted to work locally with npm link so I don't want to do 'npm publish' yet.

Comment: You can publish to a folder: npm run publish. This publishes to c:\packages

Comment: Yeah this is an unsolved problem. This solution is not any good if you're not using gulp (and the sample project doesn't even compile). ng-packagr looks like its just using the files option from the tsc compiler, and doesn't look like it works either.

Comment: This solution doesn’t use ng-packagr